# Store relational data in html5 which needs to be supported in android and ios browser

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have the following table structure which needs to be stored in html5 for caching purpose.

```
Index | JobId | JobDetailXml  
  1   |  100  |  <..>  
  2   |  101  |  <..>
```

I have gone through indexedDB, but it is not supported in Safari. How to store this kind of data which needs to be supported in android and ios web browsers.

Thanks

Comment: Use html5 storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: @janak shah I would like to store relational data, not the key value pair.

Comment: Could you store the data as json arrays and then use http://www.hugoware.net/projects/jlinq to run sql like queries including joins across arrays?

Comment: @ezanker Is there a provision to update the values if i use the above said jlinq?

Comment: If you look at the command list: http://jlinq.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Command%20List they do have an Update command.  I have not personally used jLinq, so you might want to contact the developer to see if it meets your needs...